# Backreference in Regular Expression Quantifier

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contains a header with a length of the following field.

Example:

```
fillerfillerCA20 abcdefghijklmnopqrst CA5 zyxwvfillerfiller
```

I need to find the two values:
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
and
zyxwv

I was going to use a backreference to get the length for the quantifier:

```
(?i)ca(?<length>\d+?)\x20.{\k<length>}\x20?
```

but apparently, using a backreference in a quantifier is not supported.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: OBTW: There is no need to use \x20 for "space". Just use a space character.

Comment: That's assuming you have the "x" option turned on, correct?  In this example I do not have that turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in one step. Regular expressions cannot be self-referential. They are first built, and then used. No re-building/augmenting is possible once the regex is built.

You can match the length info as you already do and use it in a second step, while evaluating the matches.

Preemptive comment: I know that one can do `"(.)\1"` to match the same character twice. This is not what I mean with "self-referential", though.

Answer (score 1):

Better build a parser: Look up the positions of `CA`, read the following digit characters and then read the next *x* characters as described by the digit value.