# Check length of string given number in string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the following strings

```
2 bp→TC
3 bp→CAG
```

but no these ones

```
103 bp→TGG
34 bp→TG
```

The difference is that in the strings I am trying to match, the length of the text after the arrow is the same as the number. For example, in '2 bp→TC' the length of TC is 2, which is the number, but in '34 bp→TG' the length is 2 while the number is 34. Is it possible to achieve this with regex?

I can use

```
[0-9]+ bp→[ATGCatgc]+
```

to get the general pattern, but I don't know how to discriminate the examples given above.

Thanks

Comment: What is the programming language you are using?

Comment: im using the regex in python

Comment: Pure regex? No. Regex cannot count like that.

Comment: Closely related (maybe even duplicate): [Backreference in Regular Expression Quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681474/backreference-in-regular-expression-quantifier)

Comment: So, in Python, you can't do that with one regex. Get the number in the first field, then check the length of the second field using the number found.

Comment: OK I see. Good alternative

Comment: Using a single regex? Not a problem! Suppose there can me no more than, say, 6 digits before the space. Then, without writing the full regex here, it will look lIke this: `^(?:1 [a-z]+→[A-Z]|2 [a-z]+→[A-Z]{2}|3 [a-z]+→[A-Z]{3}|...|999999 [a-z]+→[A-Z]{999999}|)?`.

Comment: Actually, the approach given in my previous comment may be practicable if the maximum number of capital letters at the end that is not excessive. Julio, can you provide that upper bound? 10? . Btw, I see that in copy-pasting I forgot to remove the `|` at the end of the regex in my previous comment.) – –